# Account restarted on forgot password

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-users

Previously i created account and reached more than 800+ reputations.
One day i logged out from my account automatically.
I tried to login but it shows incorrect password
Then i recover using forgot password
But it started a new account. My all reputation gone
May i know the reason for this?

My all previous post with this account are now shown as user -> user5570620

In short my question is after recover password through mail...why my all reputation and badges are gone?

Comment: See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: @DavidPostill read my question again

Comment: Is it possible that you created a new account by accident?

Comment: No...i remember that i just try to recover it using forgot password option. This account is with same email...and all previous notifications are shown...but all reputations, badges and profile setting gone.

Comment: Either David and I are *both* misreading your question (suggesting it is unclear), or his link(s) are exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I am just asking.. after recover my account using forgot password..why my all reputation gone?

Comment: If you've got all your previous notifications... That would seem to suggest your account on Stack Overflow was deleted. After doing a google search for the username you gave in your question, I am inclined to believe this is the case. (If you find one of your old posts, notice how you can't click the username to go to the profile of the account- That means the account has been deleted.) Why it was deleted is between you and mods- I highly doubt they deleted it without warning, but I don't have that info for sure.

Comment: Yes exactly same.. what you says @Kendra...i even not get any warning....is there any way to recover it?